# How to create enum values as type/interface in typescript?

Tags: typescript, enums

I have enum:

```
enum DemoEnum {
    a = 'EnumValueA',
    b = 'EnumValueB'
}
```

I would like to create `type Type = 'EnumValueA' | 'EnumValueB'` from my enum values.

How can I do this?

My current state is type of "keys":

`type Type = keyof typeof DemoEnum // 'a' | 'b'`

For example I would like to use it in my react props.

```
type Props {
   value: 'EnumValueA' | 'EnumValueB',
}
```

In case of usage `<MyComponent value='EnumValueA'>`

```
type Props {
   value: DemoEnum,
}
```

I am getting an error `Type .. is not assignable to DemoEnum`

Comment: Why do you want this?  Can you show some code where such a type is necessary?  Depending on the use case, you can just use `DemoEnum` as the type, since it is a subtype of the union you're looking for.

Comment: In react props (updated).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally `enum`s are meant to shield users from having to care about their particular values.  In some sense you should be able to change the actual string/number values and not change the rest of your code.  The conventional way to use this in your react component would therefore look like:

```
type Props = {
    value: DemoEnum
}

<MyComponent value={DemoEnum.a} />
```

which should compile without error.

---

On the flip side, if you find yourself caring a lot about the actual string values `"EnumValueA"` and `"EnumValueB"`, you might consider abandoning `enum`s entirely and just make a plain object for it:

```
const DemoEnum = {
    a: 'EnumValueA',
    b: 'EnumValueB'
} as const;
```

and synthesize the types you care about by inspecting it:

```
type DemoEnumObject = typeof DemoEnum;
type DemoEnum = DemoEnumObject[keyof DemoEnumObject];

type Props = {
    value: DemoEnum
}
```

which then will work as

```
<MyComponent value="EnumValueA" />
```

or as

```
<MyComponent value={DemoEnum.a} />
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=3#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEB1AlgFwBYFFgFcwkBvAWACgKlqkICiARCMAez0JKpu5CQF4kAcnZgAaiAA2+CAEFBAGi7dqAI35CR4qRABCgpUgC+FAxgCeMZAAUATixhR1ZcspoA3SdIBcSJqxEGxpQuNABm+MDwGGgswEgAsmYAwixgMLF0GAAU9hhQPrb2UACUnCGuNhAY+DZxBBISAIQA3IEm5UgAPIkpaRnAGEge2nzEfmz0AHQghkgA9AB87UEUoJCwCMjo2Cz4GCJl3PCxUIPjBwLOrtQgPsL0WtJy8kgG3Cp3mp66+h2zII5jsBTq1gtxzJZfMwJoQAPIqABWECi6ghEBYoSh-nooPBFmQ53o6kJcMRyIwAG0ANYQMwYrEwsDwpFRAC6oNM+KQhQcTje7m+PhJYDaYLCESiMTiPVS6WAmRyMDyBTsDlKV2ulWqtSQ9SauJoKw6WW6yVl-UGw2ko2F01mi2KBuoJplfXlAyG3z4ACIvtoZN75gtHcsgA)

Answer (score 14):

After the Template Literal Types released, you can directly use it to get what you want:

```js
type Enum = `${DemoEnum}` //  "EnumValueA" | "EnumValueB"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this! Have been looking for a solution to this. This is the only real answer to the question!