# How to declare a type which is a union of string enum values?

Tags: typescript, typescript4.0

Suppose we have a string-valued `enum`:

```
export enum SomeEnum {
    Date = "date",
    DateTime = "datetime"
}
```

How to declare a union type based on the enum member values, i.e.

```
export type SomeType = ...; // "date" | "datetime"
```

so that we would be able to do the following:

```
const a: SomeType = "date";     // Ok
const b: SomeType = "datetime"; // Ok
const c: SomeType = "c";        // Compile error
```

Comment: Why not use the union to start with? Or use `SomeEnum.Date` instead of `"date"`? Dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/q/63746463/3001761

Comment: @jonrsharpe In my case, it's for simpler&cleamer component's API in Angular after enabling a `strictTemplates` option. The answer you've provided allows to achieve the goal by converting an `enum` into a enum-like object. I'm hoping there is a solution which allows to keep the `enum`.

Comment: As far as I know, string `enum`s don't give you a handle to widen them to the string literals on which they are based.  The only way forward I've ever seen is either: treat `enum`s as opaque things and do not try to refer to their string values directly, *or*, don't use `enum`s at all and just use an enum-like object.  There may be some other answer but I haven't seen it yet.